# SUMIFS won't work when criteria range 2 is a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to do a `SUMIFS()` formula, pulling from a balance sheet with columns for separate entities.  I am using a summarized version, so I'm also summing all the values from my detailed balance sheet that are "cash", short-term investments, Accounts receivable, etc, but only want to pull in the data into column D that is for company a, pull in the data into column E that is for company B, etc.

Here is the SUMIFS formula i'm using now that returns an error.

```
=SUMIFS('BS Entity'!$C$10:$BQ$1000,'BS Entity'!$C$1:$BQ$1,'BS by Entity'!D$1,'BS Entity'!$BS:$BS,'BS by Entity'!$A11)
```

[summary balance sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqlwB.jpg)

[detailed balance sheet - where data is pulling from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVpww.jpg)

Comment: I see you're using an entire column, `BS` in the last part. Try making that a little smaller if possible.  Also, you can use the "Evaluate Formula" tool (in the Formulas tab) to see what happens each step of your statement. That should help determine where it's getting an error. First, just try making `'BS Entity'!$BS:$BS` be `'BS Entity'!$BS1:$BS1000`?

Comment: I went ahead and made smaller, but that didn't fix the formula.

Comment: When dealing with such large amounts of data, try to duplicate your data, but make the possible ranges way smaller, then try a `sumifs()`. Also, make sure all the data is trimmed, so you aren't looking for `Cash   ` and matching for `Cash`, if that makes sense.

Comment: @BruceWayne Sumifs is a very fast function and works perfectly fine with whole columns. It's array formulas and functions like Sumproduct where whole columns lead to slowness.

Answer (score 3):

Sumifs requires that the sum range and all condition ranges are the same size and orientation. If the sum range is in a column from row 10 to 1000, then the criteria range needs to be in a column with that many rows, too. Does not have to be row 10 to 10000, can be 20 to 10020, but it has to be the same shape and orientation.

Your sum range is in a range with many columns, which won't work at all. Your first condition range is in a row, where only columns that match the criterion should be included. So, this is not going to fly with Sumifs.

The formula you are constructing seems to imply that what you are after is a Sumproduct rather than a Sumifs, if you want to include only data from certain columns. That would look like:

```
=SUMproduct('BS Entity'!$C$10:$BQ$1000*('BS Entity'!$C$1:$BQ$1='BS by Entity'!D$1)*('BS Entity'!$BS$10:$BS$1000='BS by Entity'!$A11))
```

The first argument is a multi column, multi row table range. The first comparison is across a row with the same number of columns as the first table range, the second comparison is down a column with the same number of rows as the first table range.  Again, the columns and the rows in the comparison ranges must match the number of rows and columns in the table.

Comment: Should the formula above =SUMIFS('BS Entity'!$C$10:$BQ$1000*('BS Entity'!$C$1:$BQ$1='BS by Entity'!D$1)*('BS Entity'!$BS$10:$BS$1000='BS by Entity'!$A11)) be sumproduct versus sumifs?  When I input =SUMIFS('BS Entity'!$C$10:$BQ$1000*('BS Entity'!$C$1:$BQ$1='BS by Entity'!D$1)*('BS Entity'!$BS$10:$BS$1000='BS by Entity'!$A11)) into my spreadsheet, it states there are too few arguments.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the formula. It should be SumProduct.